# Find the value of the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}y \sqrt{1+x^3}dxdy$

Tags: integration

I am stuck on the following problem :

> Find the value of the integral  $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}y \sqrt{1+x^3}dxdy=?$

I see $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}y \sqrt{1+x^3}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1} y[\int_{y}^{1} \sqrt{1+x^3}dx]dy$ . Now I am having the problem to find $\int_{y}^{1} \sqrt{1+x^3}dx$

Comment: Hint: try the substitution $u = x^{3/2}$, which transforms the inner integrand to something like $\sqrt{a^2 + u^2}$. This should be much easier to solve.

Comment: **Draw a picture**, use it to identify geometrically the region of integration. Then use the picture to integrate first with respect to $y$, from $0$ to $x$. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reverse the order of integration:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_y^1y\sqrt{1+x^3}dxdy&=\int_0^1\int_0^xy\sqrt{1+x^3}dydx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^3}\left[y^2\right]_0^xdx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1x^2\sqrt{1+x^3}dx\;.
\end{align*}$$

That last integral is straightforward.